# Multiple file uploads to Cloudinary with Axios in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, cloudinary, superagent

I have tried implementing the superagent way of uploading multiple files in axios. But somehow, I'm getting an error in console

> Failed to load https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/xxxx/image/upload:
>   Request header field Authorization is not allowed by 
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

My upload handler looks like this

```
  uploadFile(){
      const uploaders = this.state.filesToBeSent.map(file => {
             const formData = new FormData();
             formData.append("file", file);
             formData.append("upload_preset", "xxxxx"); 
             formData.append("api_key", "xxxxx");
             formData.append("timestamp", (Date.now() / 1000) | 0);

             return axios.post(url, formData, {
               headers: { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" },
             }).then(response => {
               const data = response.data;
               const fileURL = data.secure_url 
               console.log(data);
             })
         });

    // Once all the files are uploaded
    axios.all(uploaders).then(() => {
      // ... perform after upload is successful operation
      console.log("upload completed ", uploaders);
    });
  }
```

I have got this example from [here](https://blog.codeinfuse.com/upload-multiple-files-to-cloudinary-using-react-dropzone-axios-27883c2a5ec6)

Another thing is confusing to me. In superagent we can attach parameters to the request field which includes API Secret Key of Cloudinary like this:

```
     const paramsStr = 'timestamp='+timestamp+'&upload_preset='+uploadPreset+secretKey;
     const signature = sha1(paramsStr);

      const params = {
        'api_key': 'xxxx',
        'timestamp': timestamp,
       'upload_preset': uploadPreset,
        'signature': signature
     }

      Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
        uploadRequest.field(key, params[key])
      });
```

But in that example, it is not mentioned how to append the secret key and other params to axios.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to generate the signature on your backend, and then perform the upload with the generated signature.
You can generate a signature via the following instructions- https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/203817991-How-to-generate-a-Cloudinary-signature-on-my-own-

You can also take a look at the following example on how to append the signature to your request. It's in PHP, however, the guidelines still apply.
https://gist.github.com/taragano/a000965b1514befbaa03a24e32efdfe5